# VBA Dynamic Rows as Range based on text

Tags: excel, vba

Days Stock Covers falls on various rows per SKU. How do I come up with a looping formula that finds the text (Days Stock Cover) and inserts my calculation in that row?

```
Sub Calc_DoC()    
    Range("C6:N6").Formula = "=(C5/average(c2:e2))*30"
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post an example of the date so we can try your code?

Answer (score 0):

The method I would recommend is applying a filter to the data set, filtering on "Days Stock Cover", and then using the formula you posted on only the visible cells.

Try to write up that code yourself and I am happy to help on the places you get stuck.